# Split the list in apex

Tags: apex, list

I am having the list . List has 28 records. I need to split the records in the list into 13 + 13 + 2 in the code. Is it possible?. If it is possible how to do that? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please share what you have already tried? Just as an idea you need a while loop which will have a counter from 0 to 13 which will drop down to setup and indicate a stay of a new list

Comment: I'm glad to see that you've received a high quality answer, but please bear in mind that Stack Exchange expects you to share *what you've tried* and *where you're stuck*. Particularly for basic logic, we need you to make an attempt to implement before asking here. See [ask].

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by means of the while loop and checking the current size of the partition. Here is a class, that allows a splitting list of any list type.

```
public with sharing class Lists {

    public static List<List<Object>> doPartions(List<Object> records, Integer size, Type destType){
        checkNotNull(records);
        checkArgument(size > 0);
        checkNotNull(destType);
        return new Partition(records, size, destType).doPartition();
    }

    private static void checkNotNull(Object reference) {
        if (reference == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }

    private static void checkArgument(Boolean expression) {
        if (!expression) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    private class Partition{
        private List<Object> items;
        private Integer splitSize;
        private Type destType;

        Partition(List<Object> records, Integer size, Type destType){
            this.items = records;
            this.splitSize = size;
            this.destType = destType;
        }

        List<List<Object>> doPartition(){
            List<List<Object>> result = (List<List<Object>>)destType.newInstance();
            List<Object> protoList = items.clone();
            protoList.clear();
            List<Object> tempList = protoList.clone();
            Integer index = 0, count = 0, size = items.size();
            while(index < size) {
                tempList.add(items.get(index++));
                ++count;
                if(count == splitSize) {
                    result.add(tempList);
                    tempList = protoList.clone();
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            if(!tempList.isEmpty()) {
                result.add(tempList);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class IllegalArgumentException extends Exception {}
}
```

---

Usage of it

```
List<Integer> input = new List<Integer> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
List<List<Integer>> result = (List<List<Integer>>) Lists.doPartions(input, 2, List<List<Integer>>.class);
System.debug(result);
```

> DEBUG|((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7))